# what is the error in my python code since it runs infinitely?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def main():
    infile=open('c:/test/test.txt','r')
    line=infile.readline()

while (line != ' '):
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    print(line)
    line=infile.readline()

infile.close()

main()
```

This program keeps on running infinite time until i interrupt using ctr+c.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jimmyj\Desktop\TEST.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jimmyj\Desktop\TEST.py", line 8, in main
    print(line)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>

Comment: There is a space there if you look carefully, `line != ' '`.

Comment: Thanks Mitch ... That was the culprit , who test my patience :)
I love this community !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your while will continue looping until you enter `' '` a space in your line variable.

Maybe you wanted to stop when pressing  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in this case a `while line:` would have been enough.